# Remove mins from the time string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Compare the two sentence

Actual sentence -> " The time now is **12:55 PM *mins*** "

The time now is **12:55 PM**    (like this Needed)

Comment: Why not format the time using __strftime()__?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
str = " The time now is 12:55 PM mins "
str.rstrip("mins ")
```

provided `"mins "` always stays at the end.

Answer (score 1):

One solution you could use, if the "mins" is always the last word, is to split the text into a list, and check if the last list element is "mins", if it is, you can remove it from the list, and then join the list back into a string.

```
sample = " The time now is 12:55 PM mins"

# Split the sample text into a list
parsed_sample = sample.split(" ")

# If the last list elements is "mins", remove it
if parsed_sample[-1] == "mins":
  parsed_sample.pop()

print(" ".join(parsed_sample))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rip off the last part of a string like this:

```
s = "The time now is 12:55 PM mins "
s = s.rstrip("mins ")
```

or split the string and take only the first part (more robust)

```
s = "The time now is 12:55 PM mins "
s = s.split('mins')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python regular expressions if it's present any where in the sentence.

```
import re

re.search('.*[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [A|P]M', 'The time now is 12:55 AM mins').group()

>>>'The time now is 12:55 AM'
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
import re
re.sub(r"mins", "", " The time now mins is 12:55 AM mins ")
```

Output:

```
' The time now  is 12:55 AM  '
```